# Constants in Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving the differential equation $$x^{2}y'+e^{-y} = 0.$$ I obtained the solution $$y = \ln \left( \frac{1}{x} + C\right),$$ which has been proven to be correct. However, I have also seen many people proposing the solution that $$y = \ln \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) + C,$$ which is simply my solution but the constant of integration is outside the log function. So I wonder if both are correct and acceptable.

More generally, let $f(x + C)$ be a family of solutions to an ordinary differential equation. Then does there exist another constant $D$ such that $f(x + C) = f(x) + D$?

Thank you.

**Update:** I have plugged the second solution back into the differential equation and it does not work.

Comment: In general, nonlinear differential equations can have many distinct solutions.  As long as both functions you have listed solve the ODE, then they are both solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry but this just makes you look lazy. Did you tried substituting the second solution to see if it works?

Comment: @jjagmath That is true, and I completely forgot to plug the second solution back in to see if it works. I just did it and turned out that it does not work. Thank you!! :)

Comment: Do you mean: given implicit equality $F(\dot{x}, x) = 0$ such that notation $\dot{x}$ corresponds to velocity vector field of point $x \in \mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{X}$ an space to be defined, which are necessary and sufficient conditions such that the flow vector field $\phi(\tau, \tau_0, x_0)$ is uniquely defined? I also do not know. :-P

Comment: "Then does there exist another constant $ \ D \ $ such that $ \ f(x + C) \ = \ f(x) + D \ ?  \  $ "   This is equivalent to asking if there is an amount of "vertical shift" applied to $ \ f(x) \ $ that transforms the function in a way equivalent to an amount of "horizontal shift".  That works for a very limited number of functions, such as linear functions, but not for others.  Plainly, it is _not true_ that $$ \ln \left( \frac{1}{x} + C \right) \ = \ \ln \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) + \ln C  \ \ , \ $$ since the logarithm of a sum is not the sum of the logarithms of the terms in the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^{2}y'+e^{-y} = 0.\implies (e^y)'=-\dfrac {1}{x^2}$$
The second solution is wrong for $C \ne 0$:
$$y = \ln \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) + C, \implies e^y = \frac{c}{x}$$
Check it...

Answer (score 0):

[not really an answer, but too long for a comment]

"However, I have also seen many people proposing the solution that $ \ y = \ln \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) + C \ ... $ "  This  separable differential equation leads to $$ \int \ e^y \ dy \ \ = \ \ \int \ -\frac{1}{x^2} \ dx \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ e^y \ = \ \frac{1}{x} \ + \ C \ \ ;  $$  taking the logarithm of both sides produces *your* solution.  People who give the other "solution" are mishandling inverting the exponential function on the left side, for which logarithm must be applied to the *entire* right side of the equation, and must be (gently) corrected...

Answer (score 0):

*Another solution*

Switch variables; so
$$x^{2}y'+e^{-y} = 0 \implies \frac{x^2}{x'}+e^{-y} = 0 \implies \frac{x'}{x^2}=-e^y\implies \frac 1x +C=e^y\implies y=\log \left(\frac{1}{x}+C\right)$$